# Error when importing excel file sheet to java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create a double array with values from two columns in java and it is not recognizing my worksheet.

I think my path name may be the issue, except that this is copied and pasted from the directory. (Except for the extra slashes of course). Any pointers in this direction would be helpful.

Here is my code:

The exception is being thrown by the line "XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

```
package adina.twitter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import  java.lang.Iterable;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final String FILE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\silbeab1\\Documents\\seedsActivity12Junv2.xlsx";
        String fileSheet = "screen_name-user_id";

        String[][] snId = null;

        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_PATH));
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet(fileSheet);

            boolean flag = true;
            System.out.println(flag);
            for (int x = 0; flag == true; x++){
                for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++){
                    String test = worksheet.getRow(x).getCell(y).toString();
                    if (test != null){
                        snId[x][y] = test;
                    }
                    else{
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.printf("Cannot open %s \n error: %s",FILE_PATH,e);
        }       
    }   
}
```

and here is my output:
Cannot open C:\Users\silbeab1\Documents\seedsActivity12Junv2.xlsx 
 error: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Here is the full stack trace:

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:456)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:162)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:271)
    at adina.twitter.ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Characters larger than 4 bytes are not supported: byte 0xa6 implies a length of more than 4 bytes
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.UTF8XMLDecoder.decode(UTF8XMLDecoder.java:162)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.XMLStreamReader$FastStreamDecoder.read(XMLStreamReader.java:762)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.XMLStreamReader.read(XMLStreamReader.java:162)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yy_refill(PiccoloLexer.java:3477)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yylex(PiccoloLexer.java:3962)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yylex(Piccolo.java:1290)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yyparse(Piccolo.java:1400)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:714)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3479)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1277)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1264)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.SstDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.readFrom(SharedStringsTable.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.<init>(SharedStringsTable.java:106)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Surely it must be a problem with the libraries.

Comment: Are you able to open in Microsoft excel? It seems like open office exception...

Comment: yes I can open it in Microsoft excel

Comment: Which POI version are you using ? (not that I know the answer but it could help to update the library or to get an answer).

Comment: I just realized that I think my path may be the problem as Garry pointed out, but I can get to the excel file using that path so how is it wrong? I would appreciate pointers in that direction. Thank you

Comment: Where exactly is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Can you post the full exception including stacktrace? The bit you've posted is missing most of the useful info...

Answer (score 4):

This exception `java.io.CharConversionException: Characters larger than 4 bytes are not supported: byte 0xa6 implies a length of more than 4 bytes` (in case of apache-poi) mostly comes when you try to read an .xlsb format (which is not supported).

Are you sure that your excel is of xlsx format and not the xlsb format?

Please see below links for similar exception but for xlsb format only:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.poi.user/12151

[Exception reading XLSB File Apache POI java.io.CharConversionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282164/exception-reading-xlsb-file-apache-poi-java-io-charconversionexception)

Comment: Just to confirm, can you open it and make minor change and save as again as  xlsx.