# Excel file formats supported by POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have gone through POI documentation and did not find any list of all the supported file formats. The [test data directory](https://github.com/apache/poi/tree/trunk/test-data/spreadsheet) on github also does not contain all file formats that are supported by POI.

I have tried out most of the format myself using the API but some of the old formats like **.xlc and xlw** I am not able to try out.
Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: I would say the officially supported format are xls and xlsx, see https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Comment: Okay but I tried .xlsx, .xls, .xlam, .xlsb, .xlsm, .xltm and.xltx and all of them work except xlsb (.XLSB Binary Workbooks are not supported.

Comment: Apache POI doesn't support the .xlsb file format. you can convert it into .xls or xlsx. [Exception reading XLSB File Apache POI java.io.CharConversionException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282164/exception-reading-xlsb-file-apache-poi-java-io-charconversionexception)