# How to read XLSB file using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

The old versions of POI jars was not support xlsb read.

[Exception reading XLSB File Apache POI java.io.CharConversionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282164/exception-reading-xlsb-file-apache-poi-java-io-charconversionexception)

As per the above link POI supports xlsb read from it is ***`POI 3.16-beta3`*** version

Kindly guide me how to read xlsb file using POI 3.16. and tell me maximum size of the xlsb file we could read using POI 3.16

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: sorry i was googled to find the xlsb supporting class from POI. i am unable to find it. Help me to find the proper class to load xlsb files.Thanks you