# Reading XLSB file - Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, xlsb

I have referred all post in stack overflow related to reading XLSB file using apache POI.
I tried many ways to read XLSB file using available links/example mentioned in post. But I am ended up in issues.

I am using latest Apache POI 3.17 and used the code mentioned in

Link :
[Exception reading XLSB File Apache POI java.io.CharConversionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282164/exception-reading-xlsb-file-apache-poi-java-io-charconversionexception)

Section: Post mentioned by "Gagravarr "

I am getting the following errors

> The method getLocale() is undefined for the type XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor
>
> The method getFormulasNotResults() is undefined for the type XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor
>
> The constructor XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor.SheetTextExtractor() is not visible
>
> The method getIncludeSheetNames() is undefined for the type XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor

.......................... etc

I checked the base class "XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor" in poi-ooxml-3.17.jar (source files) and I can able to find implementation for all the method.

I wanted to know whether this is an known issue ? Does it mean that there is no working example available to read XLSB files in Java.

I hope this query is not duplicate.

Comment: Remove any older POI jars from your classpath then try again

Answer (score 1):

Recently, i study how to use poi to read xlsb. 
If you just want to read a xlsb purely, you can use the apache test example code as the following.
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/TestXSSFBReader.java

In fact, xlsb use .bin file instead of .xml file.
If you want to do more thing to xlsb file, you can read this document as the following.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313133(v=office.12).aspx