# Nifi processor for converting xlsb to csv

Tags: csv, apache-nifi, xlsb

I am trying to convert the xlsb files in Nifi to csv. I am using ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor in Nifi at the moment, but it gives me error and does not work. xlsb are the excel binary files. i have googled a lot and tried to make this work, but in vain. please help in this regard.

Comment: i think you have to write it using a script. "apache poi" library should support it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961551/reading-xlsb-file-apache-poi

Comment: I have written the script, but the script needs file to be downloaded on local server, can i do it with executescript processor?

Comment: you could specify the code of the script inside the processor - then you don't need a file. or if the script supposed to be reusable - better to put it as a file on server and just specify a path to it inside processor

Answer (score 0):

I just looked through our code base and checked up on POI. The long and short of it is that XLSB support in POI is fairly limited at this point, and the APIs that NiFi calls don't appear to support it. What you can try as a work around for now is look for a Python library that supports XLSB, write a Python script that generates XLSX or CSV from that and call that with `ExecuteStreamCommand`.